# Passing argument 1 of 'sum' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c

I have the following functions:

```
int sum(int *a, int size) {

    int sum;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            sum += a[i];
    }
    return sum;  /* Change the return value */
}
```

and

```
double average(int *a, int size) {
    int summation = sum(*a, size);
    double result = (double)  summation/size;
     return result; /* Change the return value */
}
```

and when I compile, I get the error: passing argument makes pointer from integer without a cast

What should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `average` function, don't pass `*a` to `sum`, but just `a` since it's already a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Since a is an array, just passing a will give the base address of the array, so just pass a in the argument.